# Printer says there's a white text layer behind my text that I can't see on photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, pdf, print-production

I created some designs for print on photoshop and when I save as a photoshop PDF, the printers are saying they see some white text behind the copy on a particular line. This is really perplexing to me because 1) I never created another layer with text behind and 2) I literally cannot see anything on photoshop in the layers section?
[image: screenshot of the spread on Adobe PDF reader, on the last line you can see the white behind the text]

The first screenshot is of the spread on Adobe PDF reader, on the last line you can see the white behind the text.

[image: photoshop screenshot with no white behind]

In the second screenshot i'm looking directly at the file in Photoshop which I created the document in. There's no white text showing and this is the same case for the layers section it's not there because i've never added it!
[image: layers panel with no white text]
To make this even more confusing, i've created 3 documents by duplicating this one and they seem fine, all the module lines are fine except the last one. I'm a little stressed as this needs to go to print asap yet i'm being asked to remove something I can't see as existing. Does anyone have any idea of what's causing this?

I can see the white text while the PDF is loading it appears before the black text
[image: white text appearing]

Comment: Looks like that line of text is set to knockout of the gradient.

Comment: @Scott I've checked on layer settings and there's no knockout or any other blend option https://ibb.co/qshtPTm (screenshot in the link)

Comment: Change the blend mode of the type to "darken".. that will kill the knockout.